# Google Map - Distance Matrix API - result order

Tags: c#, api, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Regarding the Google Map - Distance Matrix API. Is the result will be guaranty to be in the same order has the request?
If I'm requesting the API to get the distances from one origin to multiple destinations, is the result sort is guaranty to match the order the the request?

I need to Map my business object to the result of the API call and I can't find a way to *hard map* them. Only the order seam to fit.

Thanks for your input.

Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Distance Matrix API web service returns results as `rows` array where each row item corresponds to one origin from `origins` parameter in request and the order is preserved as in the original request. Each row item contains `elements` array where each element corresponds to one destination from `destinations` parameter in request and also the order is preserved.

You can have a look at official documentation where the Distance Matrix API response structure is explained:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixResponses

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

1)The result if it is the JSON response it will be in the same format.
  Example :a.Single response:

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
      "Karnataka, India"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
       "Delhi, India"
    ],
    "rows": [
       {
           "elements": [
               {
                   "distance": {
                       "text": "1,942 km",
                       "value": 1941907
                   },
                   "duration": {
                       "text": "1 day 9 hours",
                       "value": 120420
                   },
                   "status": "OK"
               }
           ]
       }
   ],
   "status": "OK"
}
```

b. Multple Responses:

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA",
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA",
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA",
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA",
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA",
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA",
    "557-599 Dr Wesley McDonald Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11203, USA",
    "66-0-66-26 103rd St, Rego Park, NY 11374, USA",
    "1000 N Village Ave, Rockville Centre, NY 11570, USA",
    "300-448 Beach 19th St, Far Rockaway, NY 11691, USA",
    "557-599 Dr Wesley McDonald Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11203, USA",
    "66-0-66-26 103rd St, Rego Park, NY 11374, USA",
    "1000 N Village Ave, Rockville Centre, NY 11570, USA",
    "300-448 Beach 19th St, Far Rockaway, NY 11691, USA"
],
"origin_addresses": [
    "566 Vermont St, Brooklyn, NY 11207, USA"
],
"rows": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2096
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2096
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2096
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2096
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2096
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2096
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "2.9 mi",
                    "value": 4662
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "18 mins",
                    "value": 1086
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "8.5 mi",
                    "value": 13738
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "23 mins",
                    "value": 1367
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "15.9 mi",
                    "value": 25544
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "29 mins",
                    "value": 1755
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "13.2 mi",
                    "value": 21296
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "34 mins",
                    "value": 2058
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "2.9 mi",
                    "value": 4662
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "18 mins",
                    "value": 1086
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "8.5 mi",
                    "value": 13738
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "23 mins",
                    "value": 1367
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "15.9 mi",
                    "value": 25544
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "29 mins",
                    "value": 1755
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "13.2 mi",
                    "value": 21296
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "34 mins",
                    "value": 2058
                },
                "status": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
}
```

2)I think the above example should take care of second question also.

3)With .NET object the result JSON can be easily mapped.Here is the below mapped class

```
public class Response
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "destination_addresses")]
        public string[] DestinationAddresses { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "origin_addresses")]
        public string[] OriginAddresses { get; set; }

        public Row[] Rows { get; set; }

        public class Data
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Element
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public Data Duration { get; set; }
            public Data Distance { get; set; }
        }

        public class Row
        {
            public Element[] Elements { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but how are you getting that `JSON`?